# Static pointer to class linker error

Tags: c++, static, linker-errors

I've been busting my head for some time now trying to figure out a solution. I want to inherit from a class with a static pointer but I geterror LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class cGame * cEvent::mGame" (?mGame@cEvent@@1PAVcGame@@A)

Optimaly I would just initialize my class cEvent once and then dont pass pointers in the inherited classes.

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include "game.h"


class cEvent
{
protected:
    static cGame* mGame;
public:
    cEvent(){;}
    virtual void doEvent(){;}
};

class cEventExitButton: public cEvent
{
private:
public:
    cEventExitButton(cGame *g){mGame = g;}
    void doEvent(){mGame->getWindow()->close();}
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *define* the `static` member *outside* the class:

```
##include "game.h"

//do this .cpp file

cGame* cEvent::mGame = nullptr;

//or initialize it as : cGame* cEvent::mGame = create object!
```

Note that the *static* member in the class is only *declaration*, that is not *definition*.

Answer (score 1):

You have only declared `mGame` in the header file:

```
static cGame* mGame;
```

This tells the compiler that `mGame` exists and what its type is, but doesn't actually create space for `mGame` to exist.  For this, you need to define it in a cpp file:

```
cGame* cEvent::mGame = [some intial value];
```

Now the linker has a location for `mGame` and anyone referencing it can point to that location.  The linker can't do this with the header since multiple files may include the header.  We only want a single location for `mGame` though, so it needs to go in a cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `mGame` in a `.cpp` file:

```
cGame* cEvent::mGame = ...;
```

(replace the `...` as appropriate.)